# how can add digital signature in pdf in electron js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron, digital-signature

I have **WD ProxKey** in a pen drive.I created an electron js app for generating certificates and I need a digital signature in that pdf.Is there any way for this?

Comment: yes, there is a way to do this

Comment: Can please just elaborate. Is there any library for this?

Comment: Do you have a code sample?